# localhost it redirects me to localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/localhost/index.php?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, server, xampp

I had created a .htaccess file and I deleted it. When I try to access localhost it redirects me to localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/localhost/index.php but when I type localhost/index.php it works fine. Can someone help me out??
Using XAMPP Server, Windows 8.1 OS
    (Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.9)